# How to get passed the following error "Error in readLines(filestocopy) : 'con' is not a connection"?

Tags: r, csv, file-management

I am new to coding and very new to this forum, so I hope my request makes sense.
I am trying to select images listed in a .csv file and to copy them to a new folder. The pictures and the .csv file are both in the folder GRA04. The .csv file contain only one column with the picture names.
I used the following code:

```
#set working directory
setwd("E:/2019/GRA04")
 
#create and identify a new folder in R
targetdir <- dir.create("GRA04_age")<br/>
 
#find the files you want to copy
filestocopy <- read.csv("age.csv", header=FALSE) #read csv as data table (only one column, each raw being a file name)
filestocopy_v <- readLines(filestocopy)#convert data table in character vector
filestocopy_v #shows the character vector

#copy the files to the new folder
file.copy(filestocopy_v, targetdir, recursive = TRUE)
```

When reaching the line

> filestocopy_v <- readLines(filestocopy)

I get this error message:

> Error in readLines(filestocopy) : 'con' is not a connection

I looked online for solutions with no luck. I ran this code before (or else something similar... didn't back it up...) and it worked fine, so I am not sure what is happening...
Thanks!

Comment: `filestocopy <- read.csv(..)` creates a `data.frame` from the contents of the `"age.csv"` file. `readLines` takes a single string (path to a file) and reads it in raw. Did you instead mean `filestocopy_v <- readLines("age.csv")`?

Comment: After that ... `file.copy` takes a path to a file, just like `readLines` does, so passing it the _contents_ of a file also makes no sense.

Comment: To be clear, `read.csv`, `readLines`, and `file.copy` all expect a _string_, the path (relative or absolute) to a file, none of them take `data.frame`s, and while `file.copy` can accept a vector (length 1 or more) of strings, the other two accept only length-1.

Answer (score 1):

Out of interest, would the following now do what you're trying to achieve?

```r
filestocopy_v <- filestocopy[[1]]
```